# Pycom Fipy Board no longer recognised by any device after firmware update

Tags: usb, driver, iot, firmware, pycom

Board no longer recognised after Firmware update, keeps disconnecting and reconnecting regardless of what device it is plugged into.

Board: FiPy
Firmware: 1.20.2.r6
Development Board: Expansionboard 3.1
Firmware: 0.0.11
LTE firmware: 39529

I have a FiPy board with the Expansionboard 3.1 development board. I was able to successfully update the firmware of both boards (they weren't working before) and was able to connect to TTN with LoRa. I want to connect to PyBytes with LTE, and have a Vodafone NB-IOT sim in the slot. I have been unable to connect with any program thus far, for example, running the program at [this link](https://pycom.github.io/pydocs/tutorials/lte/nb-iot.html) has not resulted in a connection, all attempts result in a core dump. Here is the resulting core dump when I run sqnsupgrade.info() for modem information:

*Resulting Core Dump when trying to use LTE modem:*
[image]

As I was able to connect with LoRa, I assumed the problem must be with the LTE modem firmware, but just to be sure I wanted to update the expansionboard 3.1 firmware just in case. Following this tutorial, I updated the firmware for Windows successfully and got this output:

*Expansionboard 3.1 Firmware Update results:*
[image]

However, now the device is completely unrecognised by the device manager:

*Device Manager no longer recognising the Board:*
[image]

It also disconnects and reconnects every few seconds, indicated by the device manager window resetting every four or so seconds. This occurs regardless of the device I plug it into and it is also not recognised within a Linux Mint virtual machine.

I really don't understand what could be causing the issue. I followed the tutorial exactly and got the expected output. Before I tried updating the firmware, LTE did not work, but now the device isn't recognised at all, in the device manager or in Atom, so nothing works. I've tried deleting and reinstalling the USB driver, tried doing the same with the firmware, none of that has worked.

All help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the voltages on the board and verify it is not a hardware failed derived from the update?

If it's voltages are okay, i sugguest you using another OS and trying different ways to comunicate to try to troubleshooting.

I haven't seen this in a while so any information on your advances might be helpful.

Have a noice day!